# How does curved space make an obejct move toward Earth?

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, equivalence-principle

I think I understand how the equivalence principle shows how light can bend and therefore space must be curved. What I do not understand is how curved space makes an object move directly toward the center of the earth.

I think what I am missing is how time is bent in the presence of mass as well.

If some could please explain how time is bent in the presence of mass, and how curved space results in an object moving straight down when I drop it. GR is driving me crazy.

Comment: Hi Snerd. My answer to the linked question does exactly the calculation you're asking about.

Comment: @JohnRennie Doesn't your answer only talk about how mass reacts to curvature, not how mass causes time to be curved?

Comment: @Timaeus: surely the key question is *how curved space results in an object moving straight down when I drop it* and that's precisely what I describe in the linked question. However the responsibility of singlehandedly closing questions weighs heavily on my and if anyone thinks this shouldn't have been closed comment here and I'll withdraw my close vote.

Comment: @JohnRennie Duplicate of the other question is answered at http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/244139